# Why VBA-JSON Error parsing ? can't reach right node

Tags: json, excel, vba

** I have the same issue as in Excel VBA: Parsed JSON Object Loop but cannot find any solution **

Item value is "msg" but I need to reach node "recordset" while parsing, according to Json file) I don't know how to do that. It's like i'm missing something in my code to move trough the json file

My Json

```
    {
    "msg": "Operation successful.",
    "recordset": {
        "0": {
            "REFX": "140*1*70R",
            "TALLER": "70R",
            "NOM_TALLER": "MINUTO",
            "MARCA_IV": "RE",
            "LOCALIDAD": " (VALENCIA)",
            "ALMACEN": "70",
            "NOM_ALMACEN": "PALACIO ",
            "EMPRESA": "70",
            "NOM_EMPRESA": "tralari, sa",
            "DIRECCION_TALLER": "KM 2.900",
            "NOM_COMERCIAL": "MINUTO comercial"
        },
        "1": {
            "REFX": "140*1*71R",
            "TALLER": "71R",
            "NOM_TALLER": "pUERTO MINUTO",
            "MARCA_IV": "RE",
            "LOCALIDAD": "VALENCIA",
            "ALMACEN": "71",
            "NOM_ALMACEN": "ISLAS",
            "EMPRESA": "70",
            "NOM_EMPRESA": "auto",
            "DIRECCION_TALLER": "laralere",
            "NOM_COMERCIAL": "ssss"
            }
        }
}
```

**My code**

```
Function QuiterExpl(MyYear As Double, MyMonth As Double) As String
On Error GoTo TrataErrores
Dim http As Object
Dim MyRecordSet As Object
Dim i As Integer
Dim recordCall As Object
Dim recordSet As Variant
Dim Item As Object
Dim blnAsync As Boolean
Dim strUrl As String
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = Worksheets("test")

i = 3
blnAsync = False

strUrl = "https://api.renaultretailgroup.es/superget?tabla=FMTABI_PR"
Set http = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")

With http
 .Open "GET", strUrl, blnAsync
 .SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
 .SetRequestHeader "Authorization", "Bearer " & "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6eyJpZF91c2VyIjoxLCJ1c2VybmFtZSI6InMwMTEzNDgifSwicm9sZXMiOlsxXSwiaWF0IjoxNjI4MTUzNDM4LCJleHAiOjE2NTk3MTEwMzh9.PTBus4_g-Kb34NkQoMEnl1aJHAvTO1ZoUiAGVPprGOM"
 .Send
End With

Set MyRecordSet = JsonConverter.ParseJson(http.responseText)
Set recordCall = MyRecordSet("recordset")
For Each recordSet In recordCall
Set Item = recordCall(recordSet)
    ws.Cells(i, 4).Value = Item("REFX")
    ws.Cells(i, 5).Value = Item("TALLER")
    ws.Cells(i, 6).Value = Item("NOM_TALLER")
    ws.Cells(i, 7).Value = Item("MARCA_IV")
    ws.Cells(i, 8).Value = Item("LOCALIDAD")
    ws.Cells(i, 9).Value = Item("ALMACEN")
    ws.Cells(i, 10).Value = Item("NOM_ALMACEN")
    ws.Cells(i, 11).Value = Item("EMPRESA")
i = i + 1
Next
MsgBox ("Carga finalizada")

TrataErrores:
MsgBox Err.Description & "-" & Err.Number


End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is only looping through the 2 items in `MyRecordSet` - `msg` and `recordset`. To access what you want, you can try this:

```
    ... Your XMLHTTP Request code...

    Set MyRecordSet = JsonConverter.ParseJson(http.responseText)
    Dim i As Long
    i = 3
        
    Dim recordColl As Object
    Set recordColl = MyRecordSet("recordset")
    
    Dim recordSet As Variant
    For Each recordSet In recordColl
        Dim Item As Object
        Set Item = recordColl(recordSet)
        Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1).Value = Item("REFX")  '** ERROR
        Sheets(1).Cells(i, 2).Value = Item("TALLER")
        Sheets(1).Cells(i, 3).Value = Item("NOM_TALLER")
        Sheets(1).Cells(i, 4).Value = Item("MARCA_IV")
        Sheets(1).Cells(i, 5).Value = Item("LOCALIDAD")
        Sheets(1).Cells(i, 6).Value = Item("ALMACEN")
        Sheets(1).Cells(i, 7).Value = Item("NOM_ALMACEN")
        Sheets(1).Cells(i, 8).Value = Item("EMPRESA")
        i = i + 1
    Next recordSet
```

Note: It is good practice to declare all your variables, please add `Option Explicit` at the top of your module to help you enforce it.

Comment: First of all thank you!! . Ok Option Explicit
It's almost working .. I'm testing your code and yes, now I can see a value in: Item("REFX") But now I get an error "Error define by application or object" when I make parshing to Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1).Value

Comment: @Luis It would help if you update the question with the updated code and point out the error occurs on which line. I tried it with your sample JSON and it input into the cells fine.

Comment: ok done! now "My Code" is update (very much alike your answer) 
Error now: 
?Err.Description & "-" & Err.Number
Error definido por la aplicación o el objeto-1004
Error define by application or object - 1004

Comment: @Luis Can you comment `On Error Goto TrataErrores` and run again? Having that on will make debug difficult since it doesn't show you which line fails. Also you forgot to put `Exit Function` above `TrataErrores:`

Comment: @Luis Did you run this code from a module or from a Worksheet? Is the Worksheet protected?

Comment: Hi Raymond thx for your help!! Runing from an xxx.xlam file > module "MyFunctions"

Comment: Program gets stopped at "Sheets(1).Cells(i, 1).Value = Item("REFX")  '** ERROR" (Debuggin step by step)

Comment: It might be you need to fully qualify your range so you can try at the start of the sub, make a `Workbook` variable and set to `ActiveWorkbook` then qualify it before Sheets.

Comment: @Luis I see in your code you have Set `ws`, can you fully qualify it? Probably `Set ws = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("test")`

Comment: Rymond! I found the problem. If I made a call as a Functions I'got error mentioned, but if I do it from a procedure and submit in excel sheet It works perfect. How can i make it work as a Funcion? I want tomake the cal from excel sheet like =QuiterExpl(2021;01) Api call has parameters Year and month

Comment: Ah I missed the `Function` part, you can't manipulate other cells in a UDF. If you really want to do so then you have to make it return an array then use it as an array formula. [Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38451041/vba-udf-return-array)

Comment: @Luis I think you need to make a 2 dimensional array, something like `outputArr(1 to recordColl.Count, 1 to 8) As Variant`. I have never done a 2d array UDF though so don't take my word for it. Make a small test and try it out

Comment: @Luis I just did a quick test and unfortunately, I don't think it is feasible to use UDF. What I can suggest is to make it a sub (which you got it working previously) and grab the parameter Year and Month from 2 cells. so you input the year and month in the 2 cells and call the sub to run the thing.